# How can I solve web page error message: uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, html

In one web page I have a problem with one web page which never stops loading and shows a spinner icon only.

On the other hand, when I examine with chrome developer tool, it seems page source code is already loaded and there is a error message in the console as follows:

```
VM3522 auction_websocket2.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: AuctionSocket is not defined
    at VM3522 auction_websocket2.js:12
(anonymous) @ VM3522 auction_websocket2.js:12
mypage:307 Uncaught ReferenceError: AuctionSocket is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (mypage:307)
    at fire (VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.add [as done] (VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:3291)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:3542)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:2967)
    at jQuery (VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:75)
    at mypage:302
    at dispatch (VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at elemData.handle (VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)
(anonymous) @ mypage:307
fire @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
add @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:3291
jQuery.fn.ready @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:3542
jQuery.fn.init @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:2967
jQuery @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:75
(anonymous) @ mypage:302
dispatch @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878
load (async)
add @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:4932
(anonymous) @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:4832
each @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:370
each @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:137
on @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:4831
on @ VM3519 jquery-1.12.4.js:5816
(anonymous) @ VM3520 lib.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ VM3520 lib.min.js:1
```

In the error message AuctionSocket is reported as not defined. However this is defined in an external JS file which seems to be loaded successfully.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var AuctionSocket = function(form) {
    this.form = $(form);

    this.socket = new WebSocket(App.websocket_url);

    this.initBinds();
  };
});
AuctionSocket.prototype.initBinds = function() {
  var _this = this;

  $(".bid_value").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var fired_button = $(this).attr("name");
      const regex = /\D+/gm;
      const subst = ``;
      var str = $('#existingPrice').text();
      var res = str.replace(regex, subst);
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
      mybidprice = parseInt(res)
      switch(fired_button) {
        case "100TL":
            mybidprice += 100
            break;
        case "250TL":
            mybidprice += 250
            break;
        case "500TL":
            mybidprice += 500
      }
      _this.sendBid(mybidprice);
  });
```

I will appreciate if anybody can guide me how to troubleshoot & solve this issue.

Comment: What are you saying? `AuctionSocket` is only defined _after_ window load but you are trying to amend its prototype _before_ window load. Obviously when assigning the prototype, it comes out as undefined and throws an error.

Comment: `AuctionSocket` is in the scope of `$(window).on('load', function () { ... })`, but you're trying to assign to its prototype outside that scope…

Comment: Deceze, I have solved the issue based on your comment. Thanks.s

Comment: Can you write it as an answer so that I can accept it?